# What is ctrl in sysfs network interface?

Tags: network-interface, sysfs

`cat /sys/devices/platform/macb/net/eth0/ctrl` and the output is 43, and this number changes everytime I want to read.

I know `sysfs` is the virtual file system from the kernel that is exported to user-space. I want to know what are those numbers are?

---

EDIT: I'm using Linux kernel 3.10.105 and it's the Busybox Unix tools I use.

Below is the ls of network interface dir.

```
ls /sys/devices/platform/macb/net/eth0/
addr_assign_type  broadcast         dev_id            duplex            ifindex           macb-ffffffff     netdev_group      speed             tx_queue_len
addr_len          carrier           device            flags             iflink            macb-ffffffff:00  operstate         statistics        type
address           ctrl              dormant           ifalias           link_mode         mtu               queues            subsystem         uevent
```

Comment: I'm trying to find this in the source code. I can't find the ctrl attribute for sysfs. [1] which OS/kernel are you using? [2] what other attributes do you see under /sys/devices/platform/macb/net/eth0/?